# Read by character in ML

Tags: ml

I am trying to read character from a file and then writing the character along with a character before and after in a file.For example..

inputfile:
hello
outputfile:
h e l l o

Here is the code for reading by line.

```
  fun copyTextFile(infile: string, outfile: string) =
      let
         val ins = TextIO.openIn infile
         val outs = TextIO.openOut outfile
         fun helper(copt: char option) =
             case copt of
                 NONE => (TextIO.closeIn ins; TextIO.closeOut outs)
                 | SOME(c) => (TextIO.output1(outs,c);helper(TextIO.input1 ins))
          in
              helper(TextIO.input1 ins)
          end;
```

Can someone help me to accomplish my goal ?